# Optimize computation time in nested for loops?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.feature import canny
import math

image = img_as_ubyte(sf_img)
edges = np.flipud(canny(image, sigma=3, low_threshold=10, high_threshold=25))
non_zeros = np.nonzero(edges)
true_rows = non_zeros[0]
true_col = non_zeros[1]
plt.imshow(edges)
plt.show()
N_im = 256
x0 = 0
y0 = -0.25
Npx = 129
Npy = 60
delta_py = 0.025
delta_px = 0.031
Nr = 9
delta_r = 0.5
rho = 0.063
epsilon = 0.75
r_k = np.zeros((1, Nr))
r_min = 0.5

for k in range(0, Nr):
   r_k[0, k] = k * delta_r + r_min

a = np.zeros((Npy, Npx, Nr))

#FOR LOOP TO BE TIME OPTIMIZED
for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0)):     #true_col and true_rows has the same size so it doesn't matter
   for m in range(0, Npy):
       for l in range(0, Npx):
           d = math.sqrt(math.pow(
               (((true_col[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),
            2) + math.pow(
            (((true_rows[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),
            2))
           min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
           rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]
           if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
               a[m, l, min_idx] = a[m, l, min_idx] + 1

#ANOTHER LOOP TO BE OPTIMIZED
# for m in range(0, Npy):
#     for l in range(0, Npx):                                #ORIGINAL
#         for k in range(0, Nr):
#             if a[m, l, k] < epsilon * np.max(a):
#                 a[m, l, k] = 0

a[np.where(a[:, :, :] < epsilon * np.max(a))] = 0          #SUBSTITUTED

a_prime = np.sum(a, axis=2)

acc_x = np.zeros((Npx, 1))
acc_y = np.zeros((Npy, 1))

for l in range(0, Npx):
   acc_x[l, 0] = l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0

for m in range(0, Npy):
   acc_y[m, 0] = m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0

prod = 0
for m in range(0, Npy):
   for l in range(0, Npx):
       prod = prod + (np.array([acc_x[l, 0], acc_y[m, 0]]) * a_prime[m, l])

points = prod / np.sum(a_prime)
```

---

Based on comment to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67139658/2823755):

```
true_rows = np.random.randint(0,256,10)
true_col = np.random.randint(0,256,10)
```

---

Which, briefly, scans a 256x256 image that has been previously processed through the Canny Edge detection.
The For Loop so must scan every pixel of the resulting image and must also compute 2 nested for loops which does some operations depending on the value of l and m indexes of the 'a' matrix.

Since the edge detection returns an image with zeros and ones (in correspondence of edges) and since the inside operations has to be done only for the one-valued points, I've used

```py
non_zeros = np.nonzero(edges)
```

to obtain only the indexes I'm interested in. Indeed, previously the code was in this way

```py
for i in range(0, N_im):
    for j in range(0, N_im):
        if edges[i, j] == 1:
            for m in range(0, Npy):
                for l in range(0, Npx):
                    d = math.sqrt(math.pow(
                        (((i - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                                    l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),
                        2) + math.pow(
                        (((j - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                                    m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),
                        2))
                    min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
                    rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]
                    if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
                        a[m, l, min_idx] = a[m, l, min_idx] + 1
```

It seems like I managed to optimize the first two loops, but my script needs to be faster than that.
It takes roughly 6~7 minutes to run and I need to execute it for like 1000 times. Can you help me optimize even further those for loops of this script? Thank you!

Comment: Does your [mre] include representative examples of the data that the for loops operate on? Can we just copy and paste directly from your question? If there is any irrelevant code in your question (*optimize the for loops*) can you pair it down to the minimum?

Comment: Yes, of course. The only thing I can do is to give you the "sf_img.npy" file through this link : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/47042d06efa487bd6371940006812ae820210417142358/2b6ce8. You download it, you load it through `np.load()` and then you can copy paste all the code

Comment: @wwii I've also added the imported libraries

Comment: `The only thing I can do is ` - untrue , you can include a minimal example of the arrays used by the for loops. The first needs a **minimal** example of `true_col` and `true_rows` - looks like you have supplied all the *constants*.  We should not have to go to an offsite resource to answer your question.  The examples for those arrays don't need to have the same dimensions, an (4,4) array can suffice for a (256,256) array.

Comment: Why is `r_k`'s shape (1,9) instead of (9,)?

Comment: Does your solution provide the correct results?

Comment: I have revised (and undeleted) my answer.  Please have a look - I think it will help improve your processing time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Numba JIT** to speed up the computation (since the default CPython *interpreter* is very bad for such computation). Moreover, you can rework the loops so that the code can run in **parallel**.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numba as nb

# Assume you work with 64-bits integer, 
# feel free to change it to 32-bit integers if this is not the case.
# If you encounter type issue, let Numba choose with: @nb.njit(parallel=True) 
# However, note that the first run will be slower if you let Numba choose.
@nb.njit('int64[:,:,::1](bool_[:,:], float64[:,:], int64, int64, int64, int64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64)', parallel=True)
def fasterImpl(edges, r_k, Npy, Npx, Nr, N_im, delta_px, delta_py, rho, x0, y0):
    a = np.zeros((Npy, Npx, Nr), dtype=nb.int64)
    # Find all the position where edges[i,j]==1
    validEdgePos = np.where(edges == 1)
    for m in nb.prange(0, Npy):
        for l in range(0, Npx):
            # Iterate over the i,j value where edges[i,j]==1
            for i, j in zip(validEdgePos[0], validEdgePos[1]):
                d = math.sqrt(math.pow(
                    (((i - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                                l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),
                    2) + math.pow(
                    (((j - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                                m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),
                    2))
                min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
                rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]
                if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
                    a[m, l, min_idx] += 1
    return a
```

On my machine, with inputs described in your question (including the provided `sf_img`), this code is **616 times faster**.

```
Reference time: 109.680 s
Optimized time:   0.178 s
```

Note that results are exactly the same than the reference implementation.

Comment: Hi, is it the same thing to iterate over edges in the inner loop rather than in the outer like I did in my question code? Does it affect the speed?

Comment: Hi. Having an `if edges[i, j] == 1` in the outer loop was quite good in your case, but it prevent any efficient parallelization. I reversed the loop order and use the `np.where(edges == 1)` method mainly to enable parallelization. The sequential code without the Numba JIT should be roughly about as fast as your solution. But with the JIT and the parallel execution this is much much faster. Both provide the same result (since only `a` is modified in the loop and the operation is both associative and commutative). The side benefit of using Numba here is you do not have to fully rewrite the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your script, you have little experience with numpy in general. Numpy is optimized with SIMD instructions and your code kinda defeats it. I would advise you to review the basics on how to write numpy code

Please review this cheat sheet. https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/Numpy_Python_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

For instance, this code can be changed from

```
r_k = np.zeros((1, Nr))
for k in range(0, Nr):
   r_k[0, k] = k * delta_r + r_min

### to a simple np.arange assignment
r_k = np.zeros((1, Nr))
r_k[0,:] = np.arange(Nr) * delta_r + r_min

### or you can do everything in one line
r_k = np.expand_dims(np.arange(Nr) * delta_r + r_min,axis=0)
```

This code is a little awkward because you are creating a np.array while looping through each element. You can probably simplify this code too. Are you changing the data type from int to a np.array of two here?

```
prod = 0
for m in range(0, Npy):
   for l in range(0, Npx):
       prod = prod + (np.array([acc_x[l, 0], acc_y[m, 0]]) * a_prime[m, l])
```

For this loop, you can slowly separate out dependent and independent elements.

```
#FOR LOOP TO BE TIME OPTIMIZED
for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0)):     #true_col and true_rows has the same size so it doesn't matter
   for m in range(0, Npy):
       for l in range(0, Npx):
           d = math.sqrt(math.pow(
               (((true_col[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),
            2) + math.pow(
            (((true_rows[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),
            2))
           min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
           rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]
           if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
               a[m, l, min_idx] = a[m, l, min_idx] + 1
```

The outer loop `for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0))` is fine

You do not need a loop to compute this. For index multiplication, you can allocate an extra matrix array such that you have the desired 1:1 format.

```
   for m in range(0, Npy):
       for l in range(0, Npx):
           d = math.sqrt(math.pow(
               (((true_col[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),
            2) + math.pow(
            (((true_rows[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (
                    m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),
            2))
```

To emulate m and l behavior, you can create an Npx by Npy index matrix. Although this pattern may seem odd, Numpy inherited tricks from MATLAB ecosystem because the goal of MATLAB/numpy is to simplify code and allow you to spend more fixing your logic.

```
## l matrix
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....Npx],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....Npx],
.....
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....Npx]]

##m matrix
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  .....
 [Npx,Npx,Npx.....,Npx]]
## You can create both with one command
l_mat, m_mat = np.meshgrid(np.arange(Npx), np.arange(Npy))

>>> l_mat
array([[  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149],
       ...,
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 147, 148, 149]])
>>> m_mat
array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2, ...,  2,  2,  2],
       ...,
       [97, 97, 97, ..., 97, 97, 97],
       [98, 98, 98, ..., 98, 98, 98],
       [99, 99, 99, ..., 99, 99, 99]])
```

With those two matrices, you can multiply it to create the result.

```
d = np.sqrt(np.pow( true_col[i] - np.floor((N_im + 1)/2)) / (N_im + l_mat).....
```

For these two lines of code, you seem to be setting up an argmin matrix.

```
   min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
   rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

```
   vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.argmin(np.abs(x - r_k))
   min_idx = vfunc(d)
   vfunc2 = np.vectorize(lambda x: r_k[0, x])
   rk_hat = vfunc2(min_idx)
```

For the last two lines, d and rk_hat should be Npx by Npy matrixes. You can use matrix slicing or np.where to create a matrix mask.

```
       if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
            

       points = np.where( np.abs(d-rk_hat) < rho )
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

I give up the last line, it probably doesn't matter if you put it in a loop

```
      a[m, l, min_idx] = a[m, l, min_idx] + 1


      for xy in points:
         a[xy[0],xy[1], min_idx[xy[0],xy[1]]] += 1
```

Comment: In the last two codes, don't I need loops to iterate through each index in order? How could I increment each pair of indexes without that?

Comment: Your code dont need the indexes either. You can create a boolean mask to specify which indexes you want. You used the trick above with a[np.where(a[:, :, :] < epsilon * np.max(a))] = 0. Look at boolean array indexing. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html  I am suggesting that you can make your code cleaner, easier to write and faster with much less effort than you think

Comment: I tried creating the d matrix, but then when I go to the next step `min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))
`  I got the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60,129) (1,9) 
`

Comment: Also, putting into the outer for loop your d formulation, I obtain only eventually the last indexed d matrix: `for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0)):
    d = np.sqrt(np.power((((true_col[i] - np.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (l_mat * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),2) + np.power((((true_rows[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (m_mat * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),2))`

Comment: I guess you need more help. I expanded my answer to include the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

New answer which optimizes the the nested loop,

```
....
     for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0)):     #true_col and true_rows has the same size so it doesn't matter
        for m in range(0, Npy):
            for l in range(0, Npx):
```

There is a substantial improvement in processing time.  For `true_col` and `true_rows` lengths of 2500 it takes about 3 seconds on my machine. It is in a function for testing purposes.

```
def new():
    a = np.zeros((Npy, Npx, Nr),dtype=int)

    # tease out and separate some of the terms
    # used in the calculation of the distance - d
    bb = N_im + 1
    cc = (Npx * delta_px / 2)
    dd = (Npy * delta_py / 2)

    l, m = np.meshgrid(np.arange(Npx), np.arange(Npy))

    q = (true_col - math.floor(bb / 2)) / bb / 2             # shape (true_col length,)
    r = l * delta_px - cc + x0                               # shape(Npy,Npx)
    s = np.square(q - r[...,None])                           # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)
                                                             # - last dimension is the outer loop of the original

    t = (true_rows - math.floor(bb / 2)) / bb / 2            # shape (len(true_rows),)
    u = m * delta_py - dd + y0                               # shape(60,129) ... (Npx,Npy)
    v = np.square(t - u[...,None])                           # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)

    d = np.sqrt(s + v)                                       # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)

    e1 = np.abs(d[...,None] - r_k.squeeze())                 # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length,len(r_k[0,:]))
    min_idx =  np.argmin(e1,-1)                              # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)
    rk_hat = r_k[0,min_idx]                                  # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)
    zz = np.abs(d-rk_hat)                                    # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)
    condition = zz < rho                                     # shape(Npy,Npx,true_col length)

    # seemingly unavoidable for loop needed to perform 
    # a bincount along the last dimension (filtered)
    # while retaining the 2d position info
    # this will be pretty fast though,
    # nothing really going on other than indexing and assignment
    for iii in range(Npy*Npx):
        row,col = divmod(iii,Npx)
        filter = condition[row,col]
        one_d = min_idx[row,col]
        counts = np.bincount(one_d[filter])
        a[row,col,:counts.size] = counts

    return a
```

I could not figure out how to use Numpy methods to get rid of the final loop which filters for less then `rho` AND does a `bincount` - if I figure this out, I will update

---

Data from you question and comments

```
import math
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
n_ = 2500
true_col = np.random.randint(0,256,n_)
true_rows = np.random.randint(0,256,n_)

N_im = 256
x0 = 0
y0 = -0.25
Npx = 129
Npy = 60
# Npx = 8
# Npy = 4
delta_py = 0.025
delta_px = 0.031
Nr = 9
delta_r = 0.5
rho = 0.063
epsilon = 0.75
r_min = 0.5
r_k = np.arange(Nr) * delta_r + r_min
r_k = r_k.reshape(1,Nr)
```

---

Your original nested loops in a function - with some diagnostic additions.

```
def original(writer=None):
    '''writer should be a csv.Writer object.'''

    a = np.zeros((Npy, Npx, Nr),dtype=int)
    for i in range(0, np.size(true_col, 0)):     #true_col and true_rows has the same size so it doesn't matter
        for m in range(0, Npy):
            for l in range(0, Npx):
                d = math.sqrt(math.pow((((true_col[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (l * delta_px - (Npx * delta_px / 2) + x0)),2) +
                            math.pow((((true_rows[i] - math.floor((N_im + 1) / 2)) / (N_im + 1) / 2) - (m * delta_py - (Npy * delta_py / 2) + y0)),2))
                min_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(d - r_k))    # scalar
                rk_hat = r_k[0, min_idx]    # scalar
                if np.abs(d - rk_hat) < rho:
                    # if (m,l) == (0,0):
                    if writer:
                        writer.writerow([i,m,l,d,min_idx,rk_hat,a[m, l, min_idx] + 1])
                    # print(f'condition satisfied: i:{i} a[{m},{l},{min_idx}] = {a[m, l, min_idx]} + 1')
                    a[m, l, min_idx] = a[m, l, min_idx] + 1
    return a
```

Comment: true_col and true_rows are both (2230,) ndarrays and both can take integer values between between 0 and 256. You can try with random numbers if you want, or you can download the file I linked and follow the code based on that.

Comment: The code does not run: they are multiple parenthesis missing

Comment: Thank you @JérômeRichard - updated to fix parens but it still throws a broadcasting error due to removal of the outer loop. Guess it is a work in progress ironing the kinks out.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - I have completely revised this answer - will that mitigate your down vote?